# Excel sorting by month when there are a range of dates

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I want to make a schedule listing that can be sorted by dates of tradeshows if need be, but some of them are multiple days. I know how to sort columns by month, but it doesn't sort them correctly when it is followed by a range of dates.

Ex.

January 10-15,
September 3-7, or 
August 4-5

How can I get these to sorted?

Answer (score 3):

For Excel, those are not date ranges, but opaque Strings. The clean solution would be to create two columns, Start date and End date, and just set the end date to the start date for one-day trade shows.

If you cannot do that: You can try to create a hidden column that extracts the month name with string operations (find where the space is, then take that many characters from the left), then sort on that. (You can use VLOOKUP/HLOOKUP to map from month names to numbers).

Comment: Thank you for the help! I really didn't understand much about the second option, but I suppose I'll have to play around with it and see.